# No "file"? access to windows network

Tags: networking, windows, accessibility

Did a clean install of ubuntu 20.04. Then caja - Browse network - finding NAS - open NAS - every file is displayed as an empty folder.
Did a clean install of LinuxMint(yes yes i know) Did them same, no problems.
Using tablet Android, No problem.
Using Ubuntu 19.04, No problem.
Tried with and without samba.
Help needed :-)

Comment: possibly an issue with 20.04 .. I just checked on a system that I use often and just updated to 20.04 from a WORKING network in 18.04 now .. I have no Windows network at all. I'm going to boot another system that I also updated .. I'll make another comment if that one too has no Windows network anymore .. or network at all .. since my one can no longer see my other Ubuntu machines either. Ok I was able to boot the second machine .. its sees my one Ubuntu .. no Windows network but no Server (my 3rd ubuntu box) . The server is still 18.04 and cant be seen

Comment: ok here is my setup. Server 18.04 I see Windows network full. Server which I can access full and (workstation)WS2  20.04 but I get Failed to open WS2 when I try to connect don't see WS1 20.04. On WS1 I see an indication of a Windows network but its empty when clicked. WS1 and WS2 show but error with Failed to open.  On WS2 I see the blank/empty Windows Network and WS2 and WS1 and can connect to both.  WS1 and server have been around for a while. WS2 started its life as 16.04 then updated to 18 now 20.04 seems like the network setup in 20.04 has extreme problems. glad I didn't update my server

Comment: Yes i am regretting my haste in updating.

Comment: just ran some updates but it didn't help .. I don't even know where to start troubleshooting this .. but its not "settings" being wrong .. all computers were working fine with 18.04 .. this is something they changed or did to the code itself and that's beyond my tech level